# JSON: Parse error?

Tags: arrays, json, string, syntax

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "string",
        "lastName": "string"
    }]
    "departmentCode": "integer",
    "errorMessage": "string"
}
```

When trying to validate the `JSON` above using this [online tool](http://jsonlint.com/) , I get the error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
```

I am very new to JSON, What is wrong with this JSON syntax?

Comment: missing  a comma after `}]`. Here's a piece of documentation to get started with JSON syntax rules http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/json/889/getting-started-with-json/9864/json-syntax-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this. You have missed the "," after `employee` JSON array

```
{
 "employees": [{
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string"
              }],
 "departmentCode": "integer",
 "errorMessage": "string"
}
```